# How to hide an unused field in TFS

Tags: tfs-2015

Is there a way to hide a field in TFS2015? We just needed to hide an unused field since it doesn't server us purpose anymore but we don't want to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just mean you don't want to see the filed in your workitem.

You could **delete the control** in layout page (*Need [TFS Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power) installed*).

[image]

After this your teams won't be able to see the field in work item page any more.

However this filed still could be used/filtered in work item query. If the hide in your question means this. Unfortunately, no this function for now. You may have to delete the filed instead.

Comment: I mean only to make the field not visible in the work item page not to entirely delete. But as you mentioned there's no function to hide a field yet so I'll accept that. Thanks!